# Can I use a P7S file to import into KGpg

Tags: openssl, pgp, smime

I use KGpg for handling PGP Keys allowing me to securely send emails and attachments to others. I have recently received a signed email (with the message also attached as a P7S attachment) from someone and I'm being asked if I can use this email (and attachment) to extract the senders public key that I can then import into KGpg.

I'm able to view all the public keys within the message (saved as **smime.p7s**) using:

```
openssl pkcs7 -in smime.p7s -inform DER -print_certs
```

But it's after this I'm a little stuck. From what I can see, there's 5 certificates included in the message, each certificate with a unique combination of "subject=" and "issuer=" settings.

Can I use openssl / pgp tools to convert this file into something that I can then import into KGpg?